# R Plot Run Execution Time vs Different Input Values

Tags: r, big-o, benchmarking

I want to compare the time complexity (Big O Notation) of two simulations run on large input data. To do this, I want to plot the execution time of each simulation vs different values of input size. See below for an example.

[image]

Is there are R package that let's me enter the two simulations as a function of `n` input size, and then extrapolates how long each simulation would take on different values on `n`? I want to plot time vs input size on large values on `n` without having to run the simulation in real time.

I'm familiar with `microbenchmark` but it seems to only work on functions with no input value (number of rows for example).